# Why my useState from Context doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-state

Hello I try to save the fatched data from my database to my variable selectedRestaurant. I use setSelectedrestaurant in the useEffekt hook but it doesn't update my variable. I get as a value null.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import RestaurantFinder from '../api/RestaurantFinder';
import { RestaurantsContext } from "../context/RestaurantsContext";
import Reviews from '../components/Reviews';
import StarComponent from '../components/StarComponent';
import AddReview from '../components/AddReview';
import Test from '../components/Test';


const RestaurantDetailedPage = (props) =>{

    //const{ selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant}= createContext(RestaurantsContext);
const[ selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant]= useState(null);
    const {id} = useParams();

        useEffect(()=>{
          
            const fetchData = async(id)=>{
                
                const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/"+id);
                console.log(result);
                setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data); 
                console.log(selectedRestaurant);  
            }
            
        fetchData(id);
        },[]);//Wichtig, damit es nur 1x
/*
        useEffect(()=>{
          console.log("useEffect2");
          console.log(selectedRestaurant);
        },[selectedRestaurant]);
*/
        
    return(
        <div>{selectedRestaurant && (
            <>    
                
                <div>{<AddReview/>}</div>
                <div></div>
                </>
                )}
        </div>
        )

        

}

export default RestaurantDetailedPage;
```

I know that useEffect is async so I tried with `await setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data)`
but it didn't work. I also defined two useEffects that should invoke only once. One for changing  and the other for update but both useEffects are invoked twice. I dont know why and how to solve it.

Hope u can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try tidying up your sample code. There are lot of poorly formatter comments and spelling errors that make it difficult to parse.

EDIT:

When you update the state (i.e. `setSelectedRestraunt`) those changes are batched together don't change the state variable until the next render loop.

If you want to `console.log` or otherwise use the data, create a useEffect which is dependent on that value.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import RestaurantFinder from '../api/RestaurantFinder';
import { RestaurantsContext } from "../context/RestaurantsContext";
import Reviews from '../components/Reviews';
import StarComponent from '../components/StarComponent';
import AddReview from '../components/AddReview';
import Test from '../components/Test';


const RestaurantDetailedPage = (props) =>{

    const{ selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant}= createContext(RestaurantsContext);
    const {id} = useParams();

        useEffect(()=>{
          
            const fetchData = async(id)=>{
                
                const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/"+id);
                console.log(result);
                setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);  
            }
            
        fetchData(id);
        },[]);

        useEffect(()=>{
          console.log("Selected Restaurant:", selectedRestaurant);
        },[selectedRestaurant]);
        
    return(
        <div>{selectedRestaurant && (
            <>    
                
                <div>{<AddReview/>}</div>
                <div></div>
                </>
                )}
        </div>
        )

        

}

export default RestaurantDetailedPage;
```

---

Original comment

With that in mind, your `<Reviews>` element is commented out, is that intentional?

```
{/* <Reviews reviewsObject={selectedRestaurant.reviews}/>*/}
```

Comment: Yes it is. Because my selectedUpdate doesn't get a value or get it too late so I get an error in my Reviews class. It is null so no value.
I try to get the setSelectedRestaurant to work and than I can see if the rest will work.

Comment: setState actions are asynchronous and batched together. So ```setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data); 
                console.log(selectedRestaurant);  ``` won't log out `result.data.data`

Comment: It's not just that they're asynch, but they wait to be batched
`setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.`

So allow your useEffect to resolve before console.log

Comment: How I can allow it? I am new in react and just watched some tutorials and read some sites. Do I have use then commands?

Comment: create a `useEffect` which has `selectedRestraunt` in the dependency array (In your current `useEffect`, it is empty). Keep the current one, and create a second one which only logs out the new value.
I'm going to edit my answer to reflect this